# Has anyone successfully run virt-builder on 16.04?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I've been trying for days, to no avail.

First, I had to chmod /boot/vmlinuz-* to 0644 because it is only readable by root for some reason.

But now I can't get it to work, because according to https://www.redhat.com/archives/libguestfs/2015-December/msg00036.html, Ubuntu's dhclient will fail if it can't find /etc/fstab. Here is the full log:

```
$ virt-builder ubuntu-16.04
[   1.2] Downloading: http://libguestfs.org/download/builder/ubuntu-16.04.xz
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0
libguestfs: create: flags = 0, handle = 0xee66c0, program = virt-builder
libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir
libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir = "/var/tmp"
[   1.9] Planning how to build this image
[   1.9] Uncompressing
[  27.3] Opening the new disk
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose true
libguestfs: trace: set_verbose = 0
libguestfs: create: flags = 0, handle = 0xee6ca0, program = virt-builder
libguestfs: trace: set_network true
libguestfs: trace: set_network = 0
libguestfs: trace: set_selinux false
libguestfs: trace: set_selinux = 0
libguestfs: trace: add_drive "ubuntu-16.04.img" "format:raw" "cachemode:unsafe"
libguestfs: trace: add_drive = 0
libguestfs: trace: launch
libguestfs: trace: get_tmpdir
libguestfs: trace: get_tmpdir = "/tmp"
libguestfs: trace: version
libguestfs: trace: version = <struct guestfs_version *>
libguestfs: trace: get_backend
libguestfs: trace: get_backend = "direct"
libguestfs: launch: program=virt-builder
libguestfs: launch: version=1.32.2
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: unix
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: uml
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: libvirt
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: direct
libguestfs: launch: backend=direct
libguestfs: launch: tmpdir=/tmp/libguestfsOT2Jrh
libguestfs: launch: umask=0002
libguestfs: launch: euid=1000
libguestfs: is_openable: /dev/kvm: No such file or directory
libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting "force_tcg"
libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting = NULL (error)
libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir
libguestfs: trace: get_cachedir = "/var/tmp"
libguestfs: [00004ms] begin building supermin appliance
libguestfs: [00004ms] run supermin
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/supermin
libguestfs: command: run: \ --build
libguestfs: command: run: \ --verbose
libguestfs: command: run: \ --if-newer
libguestfs: command: run: \ --lock /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/lock
libguestfs: command: run: \ --copy-kernel
libguestfs: command: run: \ -f ext2
libguestfs: command: run: \ --host-cpu x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d
libguestfs: command: run: \ -o /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d
supermin: version: 5.1.14
supermin: package handler: debian/dpkg
supermin: acquiring lock on /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/lock
supermin: build: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d
supermin: reading the supermin appliance
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/base.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/daemon.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/excludefiles type uncompressed excludefiles
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/hostfiles type uncompressed hostfiles
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/init.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-hfsplus type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-reiserfs type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-xfs type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/udev-rules.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: mapping package names to installed packages
supermin: resolving full list of package dependencies
supermin: build: 195 packages, including dependencies
supermin: build: 6868 files
supermin: build: 3797 files, after matching excludefiles
supermin: build: 3799 files, after adding hostfiles
supermin: build: 3799 files, after removing unreadable files
supermin: build: 3803 files, after munging
supermin: kernel: picked kernel vmlinuz-4.4.0-51-generic
supermin: kernel: picked modules path /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic
supermin: kernel: kernel_version 4.4.0-51-generic
supermin: kernel: modules /lib/modules/4.4.0-51-generic
supermin: ext2: creating empty ext2 filesystem '/var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d.vuw17x3f/root'
supermin: ext2: populating from base image
supermin: ext2: copying files from host filesystem
supermin: ext2: copying kernel modules
supermin: ext2: creating minimal initrd '/var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d.vuw17x3f/initrd'
supermin: ext2: wrote 11 modules to minimal initrd
supermin: renaming /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d.vuw17x3f to /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d
libguestfs: [04308ms] finished building supermin appliance
libguestfs: [04308ms] begin testing qemu features
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ -display none
libguestfs: command: run: \ -help
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ -display none
libguestfs: command: run: \ -version
libguestfs: qemu version 2.5
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ -display none
libguestfs: command: run: \ -machine accel=kvm:tcg
libguestfs: command: run: \ -device ?
libguestfs: [04513ms] finished testing qemu features
libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting "gdb"
libguestfs: trace: get_backend_setting = NULL (error)
libguestfs: command: run: dmesg | grep -Eoh 'lpj=[[:digit:]]+'
libguestfs: read_lpj_from_dmesg: calculated lpj=13568608
[04520ms] /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -global virtio-blk-pci.scsi=off \
    -nodefconfig \
    -enable-fips \
    -nodefaults \
    -display none \
    -machine accel=kvm:tcg \
    -m 500 \
    -no-reboot \
    -rtc driftfix=slew \
    -no-hpet \
    -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard \
    -kernel /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d/kernel \
    -initrd /var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d/initrd \
    -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
    -drive file=/home/vagrant/ubuntu-16.04.img,cache=unsafe,format=raw,id=hd0,if=none \
    -device scsi-hd,drive=hd0 \
    -drive file=/var/tmp/.guestfs-1000/appliance.d/root,snapshot=on,id=appliance,cache=unsafe,if=none \
    -device scsi-hd,drive=appliance \
    -device virtio-serial-pci \
    -serial stdio \
    -device sga \
    -chardev socket,path=/tmp/libguestfsOT2Jrh/guestfsd.sock,id=channel0 \
    -device virtserialport,chardev=channel0,name=org.libguestfs.channel.0 \
    -netdev user,id=usernet,net=169.254.0.0/16 \
    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=usernet \
    -append 'panic=1 console=ttyS0 udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=13568608 acpi=off printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 guestfs_verbose=1 guestfs_network=1 TERM=xterm-256color'
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
Back to tcg accelerator.
warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
Could not open option rom 'sgabios.bin': No such file or directory
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-51-generic (buildd@lcy01-08) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #72-Uuntu SMP Thu Nov 24 18:29:54 UTC 2016 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-51.72-generic 4.4.30)
[    0.000000] Command line: panic=1 console=ttyS0 udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=13568608 acpi=off printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 guestfs_verbose=1 guestfs_network=1 TERM=xterm-256color
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Using 'lazy' FPU context switches.
[    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001f3dffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000001f3e0000-0x000000001f3fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.8 present.
[    0.000000] e820: last_pfn = 0x1f3e0 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WC  UC- WT
[    0.000000] found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f6630-0x000f663f] mapped at [ffff8800000f6630]
[    0.000000] Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x1f2ce000-0x1f3dffff]
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000001f3dffff]
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x1f2c9000-0x1f2cdfff]
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x000000001f3dffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   empty
[    0.000000]   Device   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001f3dffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000001f3dffff]
[    0.000000] SFI: Simple Firmware Interface v0.81 http://simplefirmware.org
[    0.000000] Intel MultiProcessor Specification v1.4
[    0.000000] MPTABLE: OEM ID: BOCHSCPU
[    0.000000] MPTABLE: Product ID: 0.1
[    0.000000] MPTABLE: APIC at: 0xFEE00000
[    0.000000] Processor #0 (Bootup-CPU)
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] Processors: 1
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 1 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] e820: [mem 0x1f400000-0xfffbffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:256 nr_cpumask_bits:256 nr_cpu_ids:1 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 33 pages/cpu @ffff88001f000000 s98008 r8192 d28968 u2097152
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Node order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 125849
[    0.000000] Policy zone: DMA32
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: panic=1 console=ttyS0 udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=13568608 acpi=off printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 guestfs_verbose=1 guestfs_network=1 TERM=xterm-256color
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 483256K/511480K available (8426K kernel code, 1285K rwdata, 3956K rodata, 1480K init, 1292K bss, 28224K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] \tBuild-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 64.
[    0.000000] \tRCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=256 to nr_cpu_ids=1.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=64, nr_cpu_ids=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16640 nr_irqs:256 16
[    0.000000] Console: colour *CGA 80x25
[    0.000000] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
[    0.000000] tsc: Unable to calibrate against PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: No reference (HPET/PMTIMER) available
[    0.000000] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to could not calculate TSC khz
[    0.024000] Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 6784.30 BogoMIPS (lpj=13568608)
[    0.024000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.024000] Security Framework initialized
[    0.024000] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.028000] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.028000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.028000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.032000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.032000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.040000] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.040000] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.044000] Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.044000] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.044000] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.044000] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.044000] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    0.044000] itializing cgroup subsys net_prio
[    0.048000] Initializing cgroup subsys hugetlb
[    0.048000] Initializing cgroup subsys pids
[    0.052000] mce: CPU supports 10 MCE banks
[    0.052000] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[    0.052000] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
[    0.220000] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K (ffffffff820b5000 - ffffffff820bd000)
[    0.224000] ftrace: allocating 32053 entries in 126 pages
[    0.284000] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.284000] smpboot: APIC(0) Converting physical 0 to logical package 0
[    0.284000] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.404000] smpboot: CPU0: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+ (family: 0x6, model: 0x6, stepping: 0x3)
[    0.404000] Performance Events: Broken PMU hardware detected, using software events only.
[    0.404000] Failed to access perfctr msr (MSR c0010007 is 0)
[    0.408000] x86: Booted up 1 node, 1 CPUs
[    0.408000] smpboot: Total of 1 processors activated (6784.30 BogoMIPS)
[    0.408000] NMI watchdog: disabled (cpu0): hardware events not enabled
[    0.408000] NMI watchdog: Shutting down hard lockup detector on all cpus
[    0.420000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.432000] evm: security.selinux
[    0.432000] evm: security.SMACK64
[    0.432000] evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    0.432000] evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    0.432000] evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    0.432000] evm: security.ima
[    0.432000] evm: security.capability
[    0.436000] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.440000] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.444000] RTC time: 22:22:07, date: 12/09/16
[    0.448000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.452000] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.452000] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.456000] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.468000] ACPI: Interpreter disabled.
[    0.468000] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.472000] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.472000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.472000] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.472000] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.472000] PCI: Probing PCI hardware
[    0.472000] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.476000] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff]
[    0.476000] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x00000000-0xffffffffff]
[    0.476000] pci_bus 0000:00: No busn resource found for root bus, will use [bus 00-ff]
[    0.484000] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x10: [io  0x01f0-0x01f7]
[    0.484000] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x14: [io  0x03f6]
[    0.484000] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x18: [io  0x0170-0x0177]
[    0.484000] pci 0000:00:01.1: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x1c: [io  0x0376]
[    0.488000] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0x0600-0x063f] claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
[    0.488000] pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: [io  0x0700-0x070f] claimed by PIIX4 SMB
[    0.500000] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX/ICH IRQ router [8086:7000]
[    0.504000] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.504000] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.504000] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
[    0.508000] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.512000] amd_nb: Cannot enumerate AMD northbridges
[    0.512000] clocksource: Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies
[    0.560003] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.560003] pnp: PnP ACPI: disabled
[    0.580004] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.580004] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.580004] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.580004] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.580004] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.584004] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.584004] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.584004] pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
[    0.584004] pci 0000:00:01.0: PIIX3: Enabling Passive Release
[    0.584004] pci 0000:00:01.0: Activating ISA DMA hang workarounds
[    0.588004] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.596005] Freeing initrd memory: 1096K (ffff88001f2ce000 - ffff88001f3e0000)
[    0.596005] platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
[    0.600005] Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    0.600005] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.600005] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.600005] audit: type=2000 audit(1481322127.600:1): initialized
[    0.608006] Initialise system trusted keyring
[    0.608006] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.620006] zbud: loaded
[    0.620006] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.620006] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.628007] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.628007] fuse init (API version 7.23)
[    0.632007] Key type big_key registered
[    0.632007] Allocating IMA MOK and blacklist keyrings.
[    0.636007] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.636007] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.636007] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    0.636007] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.636007] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.640008] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.644008] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[    0.644008] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.644008] virtio-pci 0000:00:02.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 10
[    0.644008] virtio-pci 0000:00:02.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    0.648008] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 11
[    0.648008] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    0.652008] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 11
[    0.652008] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: virtio_pci: leaving for legacy driver
[    0.652008] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.656009] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.668009] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[    0.704012] brd: module loaded
[    0.716012] loop: module loaded
[    0.724013] scsi host0: ata_piix
[    0.728013] scsi host1: ata_piix
[    0.728013] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc080 irq 14
[    0.728013] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc088 irq 15
[    0.732013] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.732013] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.732013] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    0.740014] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.740014] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.740014] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.744014] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.744014] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.744014] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.744014] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.748014] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.748014] i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found. Probing ports directly.
[    0.752015] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.752015] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.756015] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.756015] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
[    0.760015] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.760015] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
[    0.760015] i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.764015] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.764015] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.34.0-ioctl (2015-10-28) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.764015] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.768016] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.780016] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.780016] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.780016] microcode: AMD CPU family 0x6 not supported
[    0.784017] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.784017] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.792017] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 56603c66c9a77e946feb1e966c217ab15f551179'
[    0.792017] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    0.800018] Key type trusted registered
[    0.804018] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.804018] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.804018] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.804018] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    0.808018]   Magic number: 12:869:400
[    0.808018] rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: setting system clock to 2016-12-09 22:22:08 UTC (1481322128)
[    0.808018] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.808018] EDD information not available.
[    0.912025] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1480K (ffffffff81f43000 - ffffffff820b5000)
[    0.912025] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 14336k
[    0.912025] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1800K (ffff88000183e000 - ffff880001a00000)
[    0.912025] Freeing unused kernel memory: 140K (ffff880001ddd000 - ffff880001e00000)
supermin: mounting /proc
supermin: uptime: 0.93 0.35
supermin: ext2 mini initrd starting up: 5.1.14 zlib xz
supermin: cmdline: panic=1 console=ttyS0 udevtimeout=6000 udev.event-timeout=6000 no_timer_check lpj=13568608 acpi=off printk.time=1 cgroup_disable=memory root=/dev/sdb selinux=0 guestfs_verbose=1 guestfs_network=1 TERM=xterm-256color
supermin: mounting /sys
supermin: internal insmod crc32-pclmul.ko
[    0.964028] PCLMULQDQ-NI instructions are not detected.
insmod: init_module: crc32-pclmul.ko: No such device
supermin: internal insmod crct10dif-pclmul.ko
insmod: init_module: crct10dif-pclmul.ko: No such device
supermin: internal insmod crc32.ko
supermin: internal insmod virtio-rng.ko
supermin: internal insmod scsi_transport_spi.ko
supermin: internal insmod virtio_scsi.ko
[    0.992030] scsi host2: Virtio SCSI HBA
[    0.996030] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     QEMU     QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.000030] scsi 2:0:1:0: Direct-Access     QEMU     QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.092036] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] 8388608 512-byte logical blocks: (4.29 GB/4.00 GiB)
[    1.092036] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.092036] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.100036] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.100036]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    1.100036] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.108037] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] 8388608 512-byte logical blocks: (4.29 GB/4.00 GiB)
[    1.108037] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.108037] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.112037] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.112037] sd 2:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
supermin: internal insmod crc-ccitt.ko
supermin: internal insmod crc-itu-t.ko
supermin: internal insmod crc7.ko
supermin: internal insmod crc8.ko
supermin: internal insmod libcrc32c.ko
supermin: picked /sys/block/sdb/dev as root device
supermin: creating /dev/root as block special 8:16
supermin: mounting new root on /root
[    1.144039] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[    1.160040] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts:
supermin: chroot
main-loop: WARNING: I/O thread spun for 1000 iterations
Starting /init script ...
[    1.976091] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 62 bits of entropy available)
[    1.980091] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 64 bits of entropy available)
[    1.980091] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 64 bits of entropy available)
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/journal-nocow.conf:26] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m
[    1.988092] random: systemd-tmpfile: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 65 bits of entropy available)
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:26] Failed to replace specifiers: /run/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:28] Failed to replace specifiers: /run/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:29] Failed to replace specifiers: /run/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:32] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:33] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m/system.journal
Failed to parse ACL "d:group:adm:r-x": No such file or directory. Ignoring
Failed to parse ACL "group:adm:r-x": No such file or directory. Ignoring
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:37] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:38] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m
[/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd.conf:39] Failed to replace specifiers: /var/log/journal/%m/system.journal
starting version 229
[    2.136101] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 73 bits of entropy available)
[    2.140101] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 75 bits of entropy available)
[    2.148102] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 75 bits of entropy available)
[    2.156102] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 75 bits of entropy available)
[    2.164103] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 75 bits of entropy available)
[    2.172103] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read, 75 bits of entropy available)
[    3.020156] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    3.324175] kvm: Nested Virtualization enabled
/init: 86: /init: cannot create /sys/block/{h,s,ub,v}d*/queue/scheduler: Directory nonexistent
[    3.852208] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2
/sbin/dhclient-script: 34: /sbin/dhclient-script: cannot open /etc/fstab: No such file
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
<previous 2 messages repeated infinitely>
```

Did anyone successfully run `virt-builder` and friends on Ubuntu at all? How did you do it?

Comment: Links to relevant bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libguestfs/+bug/1632405 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1650740

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in upstream commit [fd60be95091a1923e108f72caf251f5549eeccd0](https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs/commit/fd60be95091a1923e108f72caf251f5549eeccd0).  That commit was backported to the 1.32 stable branch, but the first version that contains the fix is 1.32.7 (you are running 1.32.2).  So either upgrade along the stable 1.32 branch, or backport that fix yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing the libguestfs-tools is still version 1.32.2 on Ubuntu.
Building it from source worked for me.
[Check out the libguestfs page for compilation details](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-building.1.html)
Steps:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libguestfs
git clone https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs  
cd libguestfs/
./autogen.sh
make
```

I ran in to some issues because I tried to do a -j5 on make and had to fix a couple things and re-run it single threaded as well.

After I had it built I decided not to install it (hoping ubuntu will update it eventually), and I ran it like so:
`sudo /path/to/libguestfs/run virt-builder fedora-23`